# Data truncated error via ODBC

Tags: c++, sql-server, odbc

i'm trying to query a table with c++ odbc using 'sql driver'.
While i'm trying to open the table using my query i get 'Data truncated.' error. I checked it out, the data i'm passing for that query is no longer than 255 in length, i think it is a bug.
did some one solved that issue? any suggestions?

windows 7, sql server 2008, vs 2010.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `i think it is a bug`  In all likelihood, it's not a bug.  If it were a bug, hundreds, maybe thousands of programmers would have reported it by now.  Since you didn't post any code, then that is the assumption -- your code is doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

[the fix up](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/data/mfc_database/misc/article.php/c1115/Solving-the-ODBC-Data-truncated-error.htm)
check not only the parameter you pass during open but also the fields that are being transferred during DoFieldExchange() function, in my case that was another record field that was transferred to me from the sql and messed things up.
refer the link for the fix up.

Comment: What you linked to are not ODBC calls, but a library that wraps ODBC.  Using straight ODBC (i.e. using the `SQLxxxx`) functions would not have these issues.

Comment: Believe me, issues is a good word when you talk about ODBC, and it is full of them. there is nothing wrong with the wrapper class. The native sql driver is even worst.